Derivation of the number operator in the energy basis of a qubit
I am trying to model the capacitive coupling of two transmon qubits. I would like to write the number operator in the energy basis, currently, I am working on using
$$
\hat H = \hat H_1 + \hat H_2 + \hat H_{12}
$$
$$
\hat H = 4E_{C_1}\hat n_1^2 - E_{J_1}\cos\hat\phi_1 + 4E_{C_2}\hat n_2^2 - E_{J_2}\cos\hat\phi_2 + 4e^2\frac{C_{12}}{C_1C_2}\hat n_1 \hat n_2
$$
$$
\hat H = \sum_n 4E_{C_1} (|n\rangle\langle n |)^2 - \frac12E_{J_1}(|n\rangle\langle n +1| + |n+1\rangle\langle n|) + 4E_{C_2} (|n\rangle\langle n |)^2 - \frac12E_{J_2}(|n\rangle\langle n +1| + |n+1\rangle\langle n|) + 4e^2\frac{C_{12}}{C_1C_2}\hat n_1 \hat n_2 
$$
$$
\hat H = \sum_j \omega_j |j\rangle\langle j| \otimes \mathbb{I} + \sum_k \omega_k \mathbb{I} \otimes |k\rangle\langle k| + 4e^2\frac{C_{12}}{C_1C_2}\hat n_1 \hat n_2 
$$
I would like to express $\hat n_1$ ($\hat n_2$) in the basis of $|j\rangle\langle j|$ ($|k\rangle\langle k|$). I saw several code implementations i.e. qiskit, scqubits in which they say that they use the number operator in the energy basis, but they never report an expression and I would like to see which is the form for $\hat n_1$ ($\hat n_2$) in the energy basis.
Have you ever seen this kind of form in some papers or books? There are no analytical expressions?
